# SMS Hosting with Java api

Tags: java, android, sms

Is there any sms hosting that allows me  to use his service with Java api to send sms? I use it in my android app and I have access to internet.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, people sending sms provide a SOAP/REST API to do the job, so you can use whatever language you want.

Answer (score 0):

you could probably use the library from smsj[1] where the class ClickatellTransport could allow you to send the sms to clickatel[2].

1. http://smsj.sourceforge.net/
2. http://smsj.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/marre/sms/transport/clickatell/ClickatellTransport.html